# GeoServer clustering with shared data directory

Tags: geoserver

I am planning to cluster GeoServer. I can find several results in the web saying that often clustering is set up by configuring multiple GeoServer nodes which all share the same data directory.

At the same time there's some results ( http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/Using-GeoServer-with-shared-data-directory-td4468628.html ) that say that all GeoServer features may not work with shared data directory.

I tried to look at the actual GeoServer documentation but I could not find specifics about how a shared data directory can be used, is it supported, which features work with it and which dont. Best I could find was "When setting up a cluster of GeoServer machines it is common to share a single data directory among all the cluster nodes" at http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/advanced/logging.html.

It is not a given that a shared data directory can be used. The nodes could be writing all sorts of files in the data dir, blocking and interfering each other. Without clear GeoServer documentation about it I am hesitant to use this approach in production...

Is there some authoritative documentation on

- How to use shared data directory with clustered Geoserver
- Other aspects of clustering Geoserver (ie. can I simply add a load balancer in front and everything is ok? 3.2 at http://opengeo.org/publications/geoserver-production/ says that, is it correct?)

Comment: I have the same question.
It would be great if someone answer this. :)

Answer (score 2):

Juan gave the following link in twitter to more to read about clustering

http://blog.opengeo.org/2013/04/18/geoserver-in-a-clustered-configuration-part-1/

https://twitter.com/jmarinotero/status/356521026298970113

Comment: If you think I answered it please mark this as answered. Thanks

Comment: hi would you like to help me with geoserver clustring problem ? here is link to my problem http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170970/geoserver-clustering-where-can-i-find-activemqbroker-war