# Geoserver Clustering. where can i find activemqBroker.war?

Tags: geoserver, clustering

I am completely new to clustering setup and I am following [this](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/jms-cluster/index.html) tutorial to setup geoserver cluster. But I am stuck at

> "HOWTO configure ActiveMQ broker"

step, problem is i cannot find this activemqBroker.war Its mentioned [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/jms-cluster/activemq/activemqBroker.html)

> "Deploy the produced activemqBroker.war in your tomcat instance "

Where can i find this activemqBroker.war ?

Comment: I am also looking for same if you find anything please let me know..

Comment: did any one face this problem ? is there any alternative clustering setup goeserver (tested and well documented) ?

Comment: You should just be able to build it - in the geoserver source, go to `src/community/jms-cluster` and type `mvn install`. That will produce the various modules for JMS clustering, including `src/community/jms-cluster/activemqBroker/target/activemqBroker-{version}.war`. I did the build, but I haven't ever tried to install clustering.

Answer (score 4):

The first tutorial you link to is quite old (2011, http://www.geo-solutions.it/blog/robust-clustering-solution-for-geoserver/) and Geo-Solutions have created an active clustering extension which replaces that set up.

I have set up a Geoserver cluster (Geoserver 2.7.1 x 2 on Windows Server 2012) using the following resources:

- Blog post here: http://www.geo-solutions.it/blog/advanced-clustering-geoserver/
- Training material: http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/clustering/geoserver/introduction.html

To get the cluster plugin, the training material points you at http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/downloads/releases/2.7.x/nightly/community-latest/ but I had issues with the ENTERPRISE versions and found these SNAPSHOT versions to work with my setup: http://ares.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/2.7.x/community-latest/ (use jms-cluster-plugin)

The JMS cluster plugin contains the following jar files (amongst others):

- activemq-broker-*.jar
- activemq-client-*.jar

Hopefully, you'll be able to get your cluster configured with these.

Comment: It looks like there are 3 different entities working on geoserver clustering 1) Geoserver community, geo-solutions community and finally boundlessgeo community . wondering if they could work together.

Comment: They (the people) do all work together to build Geoserver but then Geo-Solutions provide enterprise versions of Geoserver, Boundless package it up into OpenGeo Suite and then there is the community version (which I use). I have had issues trying to run enterprise version plugins with the community edition and solved by switching to the community version.

Comment: As far as i checked  i never mentioned this link " (2011, http://www.geo-solutions.it/blog/robust-clustering-solution-for-geoserver/) " . I don't know how you got to that .